# Is using #define considered "bad practice"?

Tags: c++, c++14, c-preprocessor

**Goal**

In the end, I want to know if using `#define` is bad for your code, and why.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define favouriteNumber 20;

int main()
{
    int number = favouriteNumber;
    cout << number;
}
```

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#why-not-macros

Comment: Always reminds me of that old hit song by Prince, "tonight I'm gonna program like it's 1969".

Comment: Macros are a blunt, tool. Not all uses of macros are bad. Some are unavoidable. The usage in your example, however, is definitely bad because it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Galik It's also bad because it's not ALL_UPPERCASE and contains a `;`.

Comment: Nice duplicate if a little anachronistic: `static constexpr` is superior in many ways to `static const`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to Stroustrup it's particularly "bad" for defining constants because the compiler can't check types then.

On the other hand, if one line of macro saves you 20 lines of explicit code, some people will certainly agree that it's useful even if it's inherently unsafe. That's because writing more code usually implies higher probability for mistakes.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote?

Comment: Maybe it's because you answered a question that shouldn't be answered. It was clearly opinion based.

Comment: It is far from being clearly opinion based. It's state of the art. I was only trying to help. If somebody doesn't like the question, please downvote that.

Comment: "*almost anyone will agree*" - weasel words.

Comment: Oh lord forgive me for using "weasel words". :-D

Comment: The problem isn't the "weasel words" themselves, it's just that they make it clear that your answer is opinion based.

Comment: I have already changed it. Let me remark however that opinion can be based on experience and then suppressing it is hypocritical... at least in my opinion. ;-)

Comment: @melpomene Is it really "opinion based" that writing more code implies more errors? I can't see anything in this answer that i not objectively true tbh.